# How to find an intersection point with an implicit curve

Tags: python-3.x, intersection, curve

The following program I made is for plotting the implicit Kepler's equation: `y - e sin(y) = x` (where the mean anomaly `x` runs here from `0°` to `180°`)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, radians

y_range = np.linspace(0, 180)
x_range = np.linspace(0, 180)
y, x = np.meshgrid(y_range, x_range)

color = "red"
e = 0.90

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 3), tight_layout = True)
 
f = lambda y, x, e: radians(y) - e*sin(radians(y)) - radians(x)
equation = f(y, x, e)

ax.contour(x, y, equation, levels = [0], colors = color)

ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(0, 180+1, 15)])
ax.set_yticks([i for i in range(0, 180+1, 15)])
ax.set_xlabel("x : Mean Anomaly (deg)")
ax.set_ylabel("y : Eccentric Anomaly (deg)")

# line at point x = 15°
ax.axvline(x = 15)   

plt.show()
```

As you can see by running the program, the vertical line set at `x=15°` cuts the implicit curve at approximately `60`°...

I would like to know if, in that case, there exists a simple pythonic way to get the coordinates of the intersection point...

I found the general possibility to use `%pip install intersect`, and then `from intersect import intersection`, but I do not at all understand how to apply this in the case of my program ?

Does anybody have any idea to solve the question, or do you think it requires a complete reformulation of the program ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're OK with using the `intersect` package (e.g. you're not looking for a custom implementation of this), I guess all you're missing is how to get the contour-line created by `ax.contour`?

```
cont = ax.contour(...)
lines = cont.allsegs # a list of arrays containing the coordinates of the contour lines
```

Then all you need to do is to select the contour-line you want and evaluate the intersection point.

Answer (score 0):

**In case it helps, I explain my approach here (would be a too long comment...):**

Following the answer of `raphael`, I had first to modify the `linspace`, to make a value `15` visible:

```
y_range = np.linspace(0, 180, num = 180, endpoint = False)
x_range = np.linspace(0, 180, num = 180, endpoint = False)
```

Then, I implemented the writing given in the answer:

```
cont = ax.contour(x, y, equation, levels = [0], colors = color)
lines = cont.allsegs
```

Now, I found that:

`lines` is a list of length 1

`lines[0]` is a list of length 1

`lines[0][0]` is an array of dimension (358, 2)

So, I made a list from the fist column of the array and looked where the value 15.0 was:

`lines[0][0][:, 0].tolist().index(15.0)` gives the index 283.

Finally, I got the appropriate array and y-value:

`lines[0][0][283]` gives: `array([15.        , 59.36976056])`

`lines[0][0][283][1]` gives the y-value I was looking for…

I wonder if this is the right way to do, or if there are some simpler methods?